# Maybe simple - Change ID with real name from another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I hope you can help a lost person in SQL :-)

Making this SQL query:

```
SELECT c.CompanyName, c.ClientNumber, obo.EndMonth, ob.EndDate, ob.ClosedBy,
      ob.ClosedOn, obc.IsActive, obc.CheckPointTypeFk, cpt.Name
FROM OperationBase_Operation AS obo
INNER JOIN Person AS c ON obo.ClientFk = c.Id
INNER JOIN OperationBase_CheckPoint AS obc ON obo.Id = obc.OperationFk
INNER JOIN CheckPointType AS cpt ON obc.CheckPointTypeFk = cpt.Id
INNER JOIN OperationBase AS ob ON obc.Id = ob.Id    
WHERE obo.EndMonth = '202002'
ORDER BY c.CompanyName, ob.EndDate;
```

Results:
[Results image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6E4F.png)

QUESTION:
The ID 329 under "ClosedBy"
- I would like to change that ID with real name from the table Person
- Find ID 329 in Person table and get the colum "Signature" on row 329

[Person table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BR9ou.png)

Comment: Can you please replace images with text ? No one has any use of images. Cheers! Also, what is the name of the column in table Person where ID is located ?

Comment: Table Person "Id" = ClosedBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another join of `OperationBase` to `Person`, but this time make it a `left` join because I see that there are `null`s in your query and instead of `ob.ClosedBy` select `Signature`:

```
SELECT 
  c.CompanyName, c.ClientNumber, obo.EndMonth, ob.EndDate, p.Signature, 
  ob.ClosedOn, obc.IsActive, obc.CheckPointTypeFk, cpt.Name
FROM OperationBase_Operation AS obo
INNER JOIN Person AS c ON obo.ClientFk = c.Id
INNER JOIN OperationBase_CheckPoint AS obc ON obo.Id = obc.OperationFk
INNER JOIN CheckPointType AS cpt ON obc.CheckPointTypeFk = cpt.Id
INNER JOIN OperationBase AS ob ON obc.Id = ob.Id
LEFT JOIN Person AS p ON p.ID = ob.ClosedBy
WHERE obo.EndMonth = '202002'
ORDER BY c.CompanyName, ob.EndDate;
```

Comment: Is it hard to retrieve info from 2 columns in table Person instead of "just" Signature? 
Like "First Name" + "Last Name" merged into 1 column like Signature now?

Comment: It's easy: `select ...,p.firstname || ' ' || p.lastname, ....`

Comment: Strange - it doesnt work when I use it in a RPA software for SQL statements. But in SQLite it works fine.

Comment: The operator `||` does not work for all databases. You can try `concat(p.firstname, ' ',  p.lastname)` but this does not work for SQLite.

Comment: concat(p.firstname, ' ', p.lastname) kinda works, but it doesnt create its own column. it puts the data into the next column obc.IsActive

Comment: Alias the column like: ,`concat(p.firstname, ' ', p.lastname) as fullname,....`